# Cannot write Extended ASCII to file in C

Tags: c

I have written a code to write an integer and a maze made of namely three characters four characters, a comma, a fullstop, a space and a block character █ (ASCII 219).
Everything except █ is written properly, and █ is replaced by Û in the written file.
I tried using unicode character \u2588 which is same as █ but instead get the output Γûê.

```
printf("Enter a size : ");
scanf("%d",&SIZE);
initializeM(SIZE);
srand(time(NULL));
carvePath(1,1); // just for checking
*(m + (0*grid) + 1) = '.'; //source
*(m + (2*SIZE*grid) + 2*SIZE - 1) = ','; // destination
displayM();
printf("Writing to a file ...\n");
FILE *f;
f = fopen("output.txt","w");
if(f != NULL){
    fprintf(f, "%d\n", SIZE);
    for(int i = 0; i < grid; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < grid; ++j){
            fprintf(f, "%c", *(m + (i*grid) + j));
        }
        fprintf(f, "%c", '\n');
    }
    fprintf(f, "\u2588\n");
    printf("Writing to file successful, saved to output.txt\n");
} else {
    printf("Error Writing to file\n");
}
printf("\u2588\n");
fclose(f);
free(m);
```

What can I do so that █ is properly written to the file?
Note that I have written code that uses this file, and so using unicode instead of ASCII will seriously affect my code logic.

EDIT : the statement `fprintf(f, "\u2588")` works well to write into the file, but when reading the file and displaying it in the terminal the character is displayed as Γûê. 
In a nutshell, the written file accepts unicode happily, but not ascii 219. 
the terminal accepts ascii 219 happily, but not unicode u2588. Also, once the wrongly decoded character is written, when the file is read, terminal does not display the character properly

Comment: Note there is no such thing as ASCII 219 - it’s a 7 bit encoding. What gets displayed is very much a function of the assumptions the application is making as to the encoding. UTF-8 seems to be emerging as the encoding system of the future; on that point all rebuttals are invited.

Comment: If you are writing `(char)(219)` then are you sure it's not the terminal / text editor? ASCII isn't defined above 127, but there is agreement in several fonts about what should be displayed.

Comment: Try `'#'` instead; will save you **a lot** of headaches down the line :)

Comment: @BurnsBA actually the terminal happily displays (char) 219 but the problem is writing to the file. I tried changing the encoding and saving a separate copy of the file manually, but to no avail.

Comment: @pmg I actually started the example with asterisks instead of blocks but █ looks better ;)

Comment: Try `fprintf(f, "\ufeff" /*or "\ufffe"*/);` right after `fopen()` tested ok for maybe another headache https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: @pmg does not work, the file has ï»¿ as the character

Comment: If you create a file using character set a, and open it in a program that expects the file to be using character set b, you're going to have a bad time. Everything that uses the file should be on the same (code)page. How to do that depends on the programs and OS in question.

Comment: It appears you're writing UTF-8 and reading ISO-8859-1. You need to get your encodings and decodings to match.

Comment: So Ill have to include UTF-8 in the code, and I'll need to use an external library right?

Comment: Try providing hex dump of the file (or relevant part of it), and hand-edited hex dump of the data you would expect to have in the file. It is now rather unclear what is the issue you are having.